# Good book on Probability theory, Topology and Group theory for a beginner.

Tags: probability, general-topology, group-theory

This year I will start three new 'branch' in mathematics :

Probability theory, topology and group theory. I would like to know three complete books i.e. starting with the basics 'tools' whilst going far enough.

I would point out (although, It's kind of obvious)I am a non-native English speaker.

I search, before I ask here, I found that *Topics in Algebra* is a good reference for group theory right? For Probability theory I found Chung's *A Course in Probability Theory* or *Introduction to Probability Theory Hardcover – June 30, 1972
by Paul G. Hoel*.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much probability/analysis do you know already? Chung's book is often used at the graduate level and it assumes knowledge of elementary probability and measure-theoretic real analysis. If you lack this background, it may be better to start with [Feller, Volume 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087).

Herstein's [Topics in Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471010901), on the other hand, is an excellent text at the undergraduate level, requiring no previous knowledge of group theory/abstract algebra. The treatment of group theory is very nice. Some of the starred exercises are pretty tough!

For general (point set) topology, Munkres' [Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131816292) is a (probably *the*) standard undergraduate text. Like Herstein, it assumes no previous knowledge of topology, although for motivation it would be best if you are already familiar with metric spaces.

Comment: I do not knowledge on elementary probability. Thank you very much for your answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Hoel,Port And Stone's *Introduction To Probability Theory* is an absolute classic and it's the book I learned probability from. So I fully recommend it to any serious mathematics student. That goes even more so for Herstien, from which I learned algebra-I still think it has the best exercises of any textbook I've ever seen. It **is** a bit old fashioned in the presentation now-no categories or commutative diagrams and it's somewhat short on field and module theory-but the material it DOES present is second to none in quality. James Munkres' *Topology* is still wonderfully complete and readable as an introduction, but it's quite dated now. A more modern,geometric and equally lucid presentation of the same material can be found in John Lee's *An Introduction to Topological Manifolds* Lee's book will do a much better job of preparing you for graduate courses in topology. You'll also need some preparation in category theory and commutative diagrams-the best book for the beginner on this,to me, is Harold Simmon's *An Introduction To Category Theory*.

Good luck!